# Pointer based on type parameter

Tags: c#, pointers, generics, types

The [MSDN documentation of the Type.FullName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to suggest that it is possible to have a type that is a pointer to a generic type parameter:

> The fully qualified name of the type, including its namespace but not its assembly; or **null** if the current instance represents a generic type parameter, an array type, *pointer type*, or **byref**type *based on a type parameter*, or a generic type that is not a generic type definition but contains unresolved type parameters.

(Italics mine.)

To repeat, this property returns `null` when the current instance represents a pointer type based on a type parameter.

### Question

> How can one obtain a type that is a pointer to a generic type?

I figured out one way, which is obtain a generic type parameter, get its type, and then call [Type.MakePointerType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makepointertype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication {
  public class GenericClass<T> { }
  public static class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      var type = typeof(GenericClass<>).GetGenericArguments()[0].MakePointerType();
      Console.WriteLine("Name: " + type.Name);
      Console.WriteLine("FullName: " + (type.FullName ?? "null"));
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}

/***Output***
Name: T*
FullName: null
***Output***/
```

Are there any other (more legitimate) ways that this can be done?

Comment: General note: there are plenty other .Net languages - while you can't get nice C# syntax for some features (i.e. Exception filters in older C# versions) there could be some other language uses particular .Net construct all the time.

Comment: Please explain the scenario in which an answer to this question would be **useful**. Note that the reflection API _must_ be able to deal with _all_ scenarios, not just those which can be created directly (or as you put it, "legitimately") in code. There are other ways to observe the documented behavior, but _forcing_ the issue doesn't seem useful to me, and in any case if you are looking for an answer more specific than a simple "yes, there are other ways", the question is too broad.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I may goal is to better understand C#.  I am currently trying to understand this corner of C#.  Any answer (or comment) that improves my understand would definitely be useful (with a bigger improvement in my understanding being more useful and a smaller improvement in my understanding being less useful).  I would be very grateful if you could help in this manner.

Comment: @PeterDuniho My use of the word "legitimate" is meant to be a knock at myself, which is to say that the example I provided is "illegitimate".  I don't know what you mean by "forcing the issue".  I am just trying to understand what the MSDN documentation is trying to explain.  Of course the unstated followup and rhetorical question is "what way(s)?".  My brevity here is my attempt to make my writing less pedantic.

Comment: @PeterDuniho If you would find it helpful to have a more specific place from which to start, then considering beginning an answer to my actual question by answering this related question first. Let `t` be a generic type parameter. Why does `t.MakePointerType()` _not_ throw an exception but `Marshal.PtrToStructure(s, t)` _does_ throw and exception (for any `s`)? Why the inconsistency in behavior?